# How to make inject the $rootScope method / parameter into view after the method is initialized?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is a angular.js controller and view, the controller has a isAuthenticated() methods to check whether the user is authenticated or not. The methods works well, but the view is loaded, that methods is executed in three times because the method is injected into the view for three times.

```
<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><i class="ion-ios7-pulse-strong"></i> KongFuBaoHe</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-if="isAuthenticated()"><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="!isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#/logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>


angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('NavbarCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope, $auth, $window) {
    $scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
           ....
    };
})
```

so What I want to do, is to just run the method - check authentication only once. therefore I put the methods into the $rootScepe.

at last I tried another way, rather than use a $rootScope function but a $rootScope parameter to inject into the view

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.run(['$rootScope',   function ($rootScope) { 
    $rootScope.isAuth = false;
    $rootScope.isAuthenticated = function() {
       if(..) $rootScope.isAuth = true;
       else $rootScope.isAuth = false;
    }
    $rootScope.isAuthenticated();
]})

<div ng-controller="NavbarCtrl" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><i class="ion-ios7-pulse-strong"></i> KongFuBaoHe</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#/">Home</a></li>
    <li ng-if="isAuth"><a href="#/profile">Profile</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="!isAuth" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#/login">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/signup">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="isAuth" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a href="#/logout">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this solution, I have the $rootScope.isAuth parameter, and I inject it into the view, but when it starts, even $rootScope.isAuth is false, but the view does the opposite thing, that show the part of $rootScope.isAuth being true, how can I delay the view to show until the $rootScope.isAuth is initialized ?

Answer (score 0):

Call the isAuthenticated() function once in your controller.

Store the return value in some $scope variable.

Use this variable in your view. 
This will cal you method only when the controller loads.